# Ordinal parameter label was not an integer – Hibernate

Tags: sql, spring-data-jpa

I have the following Spring JPA repository with a query that fetches a cleaner that worked in a hotel on the specified day and floor:

```
@Repository
public interface CleanerRepository extends JpaRepository<Cleaner, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM cleaner clnr JOIN cleaner_schedule_record csr on clnr.cleaner_id = csr.cleaner_cleaner_id" +
            " WHERE csr.week_day=?1 AND csr.floor_number=?2;", nativeQuery = true)
    Optional<Cleaner> findCleanerByFloorAndDay(DayOfWeek day, Integer floorNumber);
}
```

When I'm trying to get info about cleaner that worked, let's say, on Monday on the third floor:

```
findCleanerByFloorAndDay(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, 3);
```

I get the error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Ordinal parameter label was not an integer
```

I've googled a lot, but without any results. What can it be?

It seems to me that everything is okay with `csr.week_day=?1` and `csr.floor_number=?2` (if the error is related to this)

UPDATE:

Cleaner class:

```
@Entity(name = "cleaner")
public class Cleaner {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "cleaner_id")
    private Integer cleanerID;

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "middle_name")
    private String middleName;

    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cleaner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<CleanerScheduleRecord> scheduleRecords = new ArrayList<>();

    public Cleaner() {
    }

    public Cleaner(Integer cleanerID, String firstName, String middleName, String lastName) {
        this.cleanerID = cleanerID;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.middleName = middleName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Integer getCleanerID() {
        return cleanerID;
    }
}
```

CleanerScheduleRecord class:

```
@Entity(name = "cleaner_schedule_record")
public class CleanerScheduleRecord {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "record_id")
    private Integer recordID;

    @ManyToOne
    private Cleaner cleaner;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "week_day", nullable = false)
    private DayOfWeek dayOfWeek;

    @Column(name = "floor_number", nullable = false)
    private Integer floorNumber;

    public CleanerScheduleRecord() {

    }

    public CleanerScheduleRecord(Cleaner cleaner, DayOfWeek dayOfWeek, Integer floorNumber) {
        this.cleaner = cleaner;
        this.dayOfWeek = dayOfWeek;
        this.floorNumber = floorNumber;
    }

}
```

cleaner_schedule_record table:

[image]

Comment: what looks cleaner_schedule_record  like?  if i had a guess DayOfWeek day,  looks suspios, as i think it wants an integer and you give it something else

Comment: @nbk updated the question, check it please

Comment: Remove `;` from the end of `@Query`.

Comment: Got the same error, for me, it was the ';' at the end of the query. Thanks, @DhavalGajjar.